# Confusing result with the string method .indexOf() Java

Tags: java, substring, indexof

I'm currently working through an AP Computer Science exam study guide and I've hit a brick wall with one of the problems.

```
    String s = "mathematics";
    String vowels = "aeiou";
    int number = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<s.length();i++){
        number += s.indexOf(vowels.substring(0));
    }
```

What is value of `number` after the code is executed? I came to the conclusion of 11, because the first index of vowels is "a" so the first time that a occurs in `s` is at index 1. After 11 loops that would result to 11. But for some reason the correct answer is -11. I can understand how it's negative, because it returns -1 whenever its not found within the string. But I'm completely lost as to why thats occurring in this situation. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, recognize that `vowels.substring(0)` doesn't do anything.  A substring from position `0` is equivalent to the string itself.

The string `vowels`, or `"aeiou"`, doesn't appear anywhere in `"mathematics"`, so `indexOf` will return `-1` 11 times (`"mathematics"` is length `11`).  Therefore, the result of `number` at the end is `-11`.

While it's not clear exactly what you want, if you want to get the positions of each of the vowels in the string `s`, you'll have to re-write your `for` loop and use `charAt(i)` or `substring(i, i + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because substring(0) returns the complete string.

You can try this to understand:

```
System.out.println(vowels.substring(0));
```

The result of vowels.substring(0) is "aeiou", and "aeiou" does not exist in String s ("mathematics").